Copy sheet to another workbook without reference to original wookbook
I have a sheet with formula reference from beside sheet.
=SUMIF(NAIJIW!$X$4:$X$27460, $C8, NAIJIW!I$4:I$27460)

When i copy this sheet to another workbook, that formula change by reference to original workbook

How to copy that sheet to another workbook without refence to original workbook?


I think finding and replacing all references to the source workbook (replace [SMPS.xlsm] with nothing (leave replace with box empty) is the only way; let's see if someone else comes up with a better way

@tinazmu could you let me know how to replace ?
Because, they are formulas.

Thanks you @tinazmu .
i already solve it by your way

Another way to achieve this with VBA code. But keep in mind that the destination workbook must contain a worksheet named NAIJIW.
Sub CopySheetNoLinks()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy After:=Workbooks("DestBook.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=ThisWorkbook.Name, _
        NewName:=ActiveWorkbook.Name, Type:=xlExcelLinks
End Sub

Sheet2 is the name of sheet to be copied, DestBook.xlsx is the destination workbook name. The destination workbook must be open. The Sheet2 will be copied after the first sheet in the destination. You can change this if necessary.

I think finding and replacing all references to the source workbook (replace [SMPS.xlsm] with nothing (leave replace with box empty) is the only way. I hope someone else comes up with a better way.
Say your sheet is called MySheet:
Make sure that you have the referred sheet already in the target workbook (i.e. NAIJIW must already exist in your target workbook, before you copy MySheet; if not, copy that one first; or create a new sheet in the target workbook with that name).
Now copy MySheet to the target workbook; I presume you right-click on the worksheet tab, and choose  Move or Copy, then choose the target workbook under To book: drop-down, tick the 'Create a copy =' checkbox (if you don't want your original sheet to be deleted.
Now you have MySheet in its new workbook, but referring to the old workbook: [SMPS.xlsm].
To remove these references just use EXCEL's find and Replace (CTRL-F, p); in the Find what: box, type [SMPS.xlsm]; leave the Replace with: empty; make sure that Look in: is Formulas; click Replace All.
That should be it

Thank @tinazmu.
I find the way to replace a text in the formula
i using the code below:
Private Sub ReplaceFormula(ByVal iRange As Range, ByVal originalText As String, Optional ByVal alterTex As String = "")
  Dim c As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each c In iRange.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
    c.Formula = Replace(c.Formula, originalText, alterTex)
  Next c
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub


I didn't realise you were doing it in VBA; should have asked.
